# Local device language on Android - which API would return it without placing the per-app language preference first?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, localization, android-jetpack-compose

What is the proper way to read the **android device language**, set via General Management, Language and input? And ***disregard*** the language preference set via General Management - App Languages - for the app.([Per-app language preferences)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages)

It seems only one API - LocaleListCompat.getDefault() correctly identifies the device language, but even that returns the In-App-selected language (if one is set) ***first*** instead of the device language.

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/os/LocaleListCompat), it behaves as intended:

> The result is guaranteed to include the default Locale returned by
> Locale.getDefault(), but not necessarily at the top of the list. The
> default locale not being at the top of the list is an indication that
> the system has set the default locale to one of the user's other
> preferred locales, having concluded that the primary preference is not
> supported but a secondary preference is.

OK, but which API then can I use to get the real device language - set device-wide - regardless of what user chooses as the preferred language for this particular app?

This is a list of APIs I tried:

[image: list of apis tried]

And here are the results - first on Samsung Galaxy 9, the default language set to the Filipino language. There is no per-app language preference set.

[image: samsung galaxy 9]

Only one API correctly identifies Filipino as the selected default device language (showing it at the top):

> LocalListCompat.getDefault()

[image]

And here is Galaxy 20. Dutch is chosen as the default device language. Russian is chosen as App-language (via General Management, App Languages - Per-App Language Preference)

[image]

None of the APIs identify Dutch as the selected language, and they  identify Russian as the default language (chosen via Per-App language preference in settings), whereas it should have been Dutch at the top, and English as the fallback (second), as it's clearly second on the list.

**Note:** When I opened Telegram after trying this, it did prompt me to switch to Dutch - so the problem is specific to the APIs I used -  when calling them ***within*** the app itself.

So how do I get the default device language without having the in-app language returned first?

[image]

Comment: While screenshots from the device can be images, other parts of your question should be in text, as [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/295004). It may also help to identify by model number the devices, what is the device Google account locale/region, was a SIM used/active during testing.